# Wildcards in OGNL?

Tags: ognl

I had to write some OGNL to look something up in a table, sort of like using a C# dictionary. This was easy enough:

```
#mapping=#{"XYZ":"1234","YZX":"5678"},
#mapping.get(this.A.toString())
```

But now my requirements have changed. Now I need to make some more complex rules, and I'm not sure if OGNL can do it. I have several requirements for the updated expression. I now have two separate values and their combinations to worry about. We'll call the values A and B. The rules are something like this:

1. If a particular value for A appears, always return the same value.
2. If certain combinations of values of A and B appear, return another value.
3. If any value for A appears other than the ones we specifically care about, return another value.

If I have a list of all possible values for A and B, I can make a really big hashtable with each concatenation of them and the proper value to return for each case. Seems like this would be a lot easier if I could use wildcards. Does anyone have a thought on how to implement this, or if it's possible with OGNL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, I'd probably move this logic out to a java method. You might eventually figure out how to do what you want in ognl - like ? style null handlers also supported - but why bother?

It supports projections and as many recursive evaluations as java language supports but I don't know. . I'd opt to move this elsewhere, and I've made significant contributions / bug fixes / changes to ognl itself and know it well.

Comment: I actually got it working in ognl with lambda expressions, but yeah, I wish I hadn't.